# Autocomplete options not showing on wix mobile site

Tags: javascript, mobile, autocomplete, velo

Long time listener first time caller here
Wix mobile site not letting user type in drop down box and autocomplete but desktop site does …
Anyone had this issue and what code can I put in mobile end to make it worth both .?

I want autocomplete from dataset to appear but user able type letter before it appears